# Destroy / Release store instance

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I work in a navigation view. In this navigation view, you can stumble on a profile page.In this profile page you can see others profiles related to the current profile (basically pictures displayed in a dataview). You can navigate to other profile views by taping on these profiles.

Every time, the user click on a profile pictures, I create a new instance of the profile view and a new instance of the profile store.

Now, what I want to do, when the user goes back, (so when the view is popped) is delete the instance of the store associated to the instance of the profile view.

I already know when and how to delete the view, I just want to know how to delete the store and any reference to it.

**Update** : StoreManager

I just discovered the `Ext.StoreManager.unregister` function. Is it enough or is there something that should be done, to release the store (in order to free memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.getStore('storeId').destroy();
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore

Comment: You can still see the store in Ext.StoreManager.all after you destroy it. The answer is probably to use the unregister function of the StoreManager

Comment: I had to use the private 'autoDestroy' flag on Store to get my store instances to completely be released. (All the usual warnings about using a private flag apply.) No combination of StoreManager.unregister or Store.destroy would accomplish complete removal of the store. (Sencha Touch 2.3.0)